# Prove $C_c(R^n)$ is a subspace of $L^p$ but is not closed in it.

Tags: real-analysis

It's s subspace of $L^p(R^n)$ because continuous functions of compact support are bounded, and compact sets have finite measure so ${C_c(R^n)}$ is a subspace of ${L^p(R^n)}$.
I've difficult to find a counterexample for the not clousure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A result typically covered in Real Analysis classes is that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $0<p<\infty$. This means that the closure of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, viewed as a subspace of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is the whole space. Now if $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ was closed (i.e. equal to its closure), it would follow that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n) = L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is false.

Let me also give a more down-to-earth approach: Take any continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with non-compact support such that $\int |f|^p <\infty$. For example, you could take an $n$-dimensional bell curve. Then (the equivalence class of) $f$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\setminus C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If we can construct a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which converges to $f$ (in the $p$-norm), then $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ cannot be closed.

Constructing such a sequence is not too hard: For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define $f_n$ as
$$
f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & |x|\le n\\
0 & |x|\ge n+1\\ 
\end{cases}
$$
and linearly interpolate for $n<|x|<n+1$. Then all the $f_n$ are continuous with compact support, and $f_n\to f$ like we wanted.